# Closed form representation of alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I consider the following series
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^{n+2}}{n+2}} \stackrel{?}{=} 1-\ln(2)
\end{align}
Wolfram tells me that it is equal to $1-\ln(2)$.
I know the following
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}} = \ln(2)\\
&\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^{n+2}}{n+2}} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k+1}}
\end{align}
I thus need to show that the following is true, but I would not know how to do it.
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k+1}} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}} = 1
\end{align}

Comment: if you put both series into one and start computing the first terms, you will notice that something nice is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n+2}}{n+2}=$

$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^k}{k} -1+1=$

$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^k}{k} +1=$

$1+ (-1)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}=$

$1- \log 2.$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k+1}} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}}
 &=
\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k+1}} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k+1}}
\\ &=
\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k+1}} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k+1}}+1
\\ &=1
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k+1}}=\frac 1 2-\frac 1 3+\frac 1 4+\cdots$ and  $\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}}=1-\frac 1 2+\frac 1 3-\frac 1 4+\cdots$. What happens when you add these two?